# First number of result of template is delete

Tags: handlebars.js

In a view of Brite.js the result of render a handlebars.js template is `1 <span>products</span>` but when display the view the number is not show, it only show the span tag and the text.

Template is:

```
{{num}} <span>products</span>
```

The view only in create has function that return result of render template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brite.js view needs to return (or resolve) to an HTML element, an HTML string (starting with a tag), or a jQuery object pointing to an HTML Element.

So, something like this should work:

```
var counter = 0;
brite.registerView("MyView",{

  create: function(){
     counter++;
     return "<div>" +  + "</div>");
  }

});
```

Then, every time you call `brite.display("MyView","body")`, it will add a new div to `<body>` in this case, with the incremented counter.

Obviously, the create method can use any templating engine like Handlebars, but the string needs to be an HTML tag.